# How can I prompt the user for input, and then remove the prompt after?

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell, terminal

Given this simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "--- EARLIER OUTPUT FOM SCRIPT ---""

read -p "What's your name? " name
echo "Hello $name"

echo "--- LATER OUTPUT FOM SCRIPT"
```

The resulting output would look like this:

```
--- EARLIER OUTPUT FROM SCRIPT ---
What's your name? Foo
Hello foo
--- LATER OUTPUT FROM SCRIPT ---
```

How can I remove the prompt after it is answered so that it's not visible and script output continues as if the prompt never happened? Is this possible with `read` or am I going to have to do something more involved? Ideally I'd want this to be fairly portable (i.e. macOS/BSD and GNU).

This is the goal:

```
--- EARLIER OUTPUT FROM SCRIPT ---
Hello foo
--- LATER OUTPUT FROM SCRIPT ---
```

Answer (score 0):

**Almost does what you want**

This might work for you =>  " **clear && printf '\e[3J'** " (clears all text and
    sets terminal empty). For good measure you could also reset the terminal (probably not ideal in a script) with " tput reset ". You would have to save the previous output and reprint it.